# Examples of Android Widget Types

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm porting an app from iOS to Android, I've read a couple of books and am kind of learning as I go along.  One thing I'm having trouble with is finding a document, app or website that will show me the different types of widgets available and what they're called.  Does anybody know of any resource that does this?

[image]

I'm asking specifically because I stumbled on this lovely thing in the Android docs and can't for the life of me find out what the widget is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular widget is the [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).  Most of the widgets are in the [android.widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/package-summary.html) package.  You can also look at the [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) developer guide that has some good information.

Comment: I did actually look in the User Interface guide, went to the Pickers section under Input Controls and it isn't mentioned - but thanks very much for the info.